# Sort data from a MutableList in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, mutable

I'm new to Kotlin and need to ask some questions about ordering a `MutableList<MyObject>`. As I understand it, I can do a `myMutableList.sortBy {it.int}` and a `myMutableList.sortByDescending {it.int}` for both `Int` and `String`. But return is always a `Unit` and not a `MutableList`.

Where am I going wrong and how do I proceed?

Answer (score 17):

Mutable means changeable, so it makes sense that rather than `sortBy` returning a new list, the order of the items has changed "in place" in the current list.

Try looking at the order of the items in `myMutableList` after the `sortBy` and you will see they are now in the order requested.

Answer (score 7):

The kotlin functions [`sort`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html), [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html), [`sortWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html) etc. all sort the items in the list itself.
From the documentation of [`sort`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html):

> Sorts the array in-place according to the natural order of its elements.

If you don't want to sort the elements in-place but rather return a sorted list (your base doesn't need to be a `MutableList`), you can use [`sorted`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted.html), [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html), [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html), etc:

> Returns a list of all elements sorted according to their natural sort order.

Answer (score 5):

You can use mutableList's extension methods. like

```
list.sort()
list.sortBy{it.value}
list.sortByDescending()
list.sortByDescending{it.value}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this with the properties of the object inside the list, so let's say you have an object with a string and a number

```
data class MyObject(var name:String,var number:Int)
```

add some values to it

```
 val myObjectList: MutableList<MyObject>? = mutableListOf()
 myObjectList!!.add(MyObject("C",3))
 myObjectList.add(MyObject("B",1))
 myObjectList.add(MyObject("A",2))
```

And then you can sort it by either one of its properties, it'll return a mutable list with the sorted values

```
var sortedByName =  myObjectList.sortedBy { myObject -> myObject.name }
var sortedByNumber =  myObjectList.sortedBy { myObject -> myObject.number }
```

Comment: you can sort with ```var sortedByName =  myObjectList.sortedBy { it.name }``` And beside that you can sort with ```myObjectList.sortedByDescending { it.name }```

Answer (score 1):

To sort a mutable list you can use:

```
Collections.sort(myMutableList)
Collections.reverse(myMutableList)  //To sort the list by descending order
```

And in kotlin you can use the contract kotlin stdlib instruction, and it becomes:

```
myMutableList.sort()
myMutableList.reverse()  //To sort the list by descending order
```

And then you can call `myMutableList` and it's order is changed, like this:

```
val myMutableList = mutableListOf(8,5,4,6)

System.out.println("myMutableList: ${myMutableList[0]}")

myMutableList.sort()

System.out.println("myMutableList: ${myMutableList[0]}")
```

Output:

```
myMutableList: 8
myMutableList: 4
```